# Is it possible to open a framerJS project directly from the MacOS Finder?

Tags: macos, framerjs

MacOS finder supports opening files from the finder.  Based on their extension a specified program will open.

FramerJS relies on a project folder which doesn't include this option.

Is there a way I can open a framer project by maybe opening one of the folder files in framer?

How can this be done?